# Can I export blender's drawing lines for using in clipstudio?

Tags: modeling, rendering, objects, export, draw-mode

I want to find to much easier way to what I make my web comics. so I found blender's surface drawing.

and trying to export drawing line for clip studio. but I can't.

Is this possible? clip studio's 3d object file form is *.fbx or *.obj

I want turn around my sketch lines without limits.

Comment: clip studio's 3d object file form is *.fbx or *.obj (Only I know is this two forms. maybe it more... )

Answer (score 0):

Convert the grease pencil to a curve or a mesh.

[image]

Then export as the format you need.

Note that the format will determine what attributes will get saved as part of the file, most likely only the outline.

Comment: OMG..THX U SO MUCH. IM TRYING